# Maven Cobertura and Package without running Unit Tests Twice

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, maven-cobertura-plugin

I am running maven like this:

```
mvn clean cobertura:cobertura package
```

I am noticing that my unit tests get run twice (thus doubling my build time). Is there a way to run cobertura AND generate the package in the same command without running tests twice?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to do it !

Comment: possible duplicate of [double unit test reporting with hudson and maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098445/double-unit-test-reporting-with-hudson-and-maven)

Comment: 333kenshin : Perhaps they might share the same root cause, however, my question is regarding command line maven in general and not regarding hudson double reporting unit tests.

Comment: See

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732995/running-junits-and-cobertura-with-maven

Answer (score 3):

An easy way would be to run two separate commands.  In Bash it's then easy to chain them together into one line:

```
mvn clean cobertura:cobertura && mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

The first bit:

```
mvn clean cobertura:cobertura
```

Does clean, runs the tests and generates the coverage report.

The second bit:

```
mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Does the packaging, but tells it not to run the tests.

The `&&` is there so that if the first command fails, then it won't try to run the second.

Comment: Be aware that this way integration tests are not executed any more! If you want integration tests `mvn clean cobertura:cobertura-integration-test` is your friend